# C# using list to find elements in class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use List.Contains to find if item in list, has it's bool true or false

Problem is, no matter if the bool is true or false, function always return's false.. her's an example

```
public class RecepieClass
{
    public Recepie recepie;
    public bool isUnlocked;
}

public class RecepieList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<RecepieClass> recepies = new List<RecepieClass>();

    public void SelectRecepie(Recepie r)
    {
        Debug.Log(recepies.Contains(new RecepieClass{recepie = r, isUnlocked = false}));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are checking if an object you just created is in the list. And your `RecepieClass` does not contain any custom `Equals` method

Comment: on which criteria you want to find first element ?

Comment: I want to find if isUnlocked is either true or false, for recepie that i'm checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop, and examine the recipe property of each RecipeClass item.  If you know that the Recepie parameter being passed to the function is the actual instance of one of the RecepieClass items in your list, then the default Object.Equals method will work.  If it is another instance, you'll need to define your own Equals method (i.e., Recepie should implement IEquatable).

```
public class RecepieClass
{
    public Recepie recepie;
    public bool isUnlocked;
}

public class RecepieList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<RecepieClass> recepies = new List<RecepieClass>();

    public void SelectRecepie(Recepie r)
    {
        foreach (var rc in recepies) {
            if (rc.recepie.Equals(r)) {
                // you've found it
                if (rc.isUnlocked) {
                    // do something
                } else {
                    // do something else
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're into the whole brevity thing, you could use System.Linq.FirstOrDefault (just be prepared for it to return a null).

```
public void SelectRecepie(Recepie r)
{
    if (recepies.FirstOrDefault(rc => rc.recepie.Equals(r))?.isUnlocked ?? false) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Well was thinink about for loop, but tought i could do it in cleaner way tbh - thanks for response!

Comment: if value is uniq add a break when finding no need to test all others values

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if your value r is unique in List or not. i just trap the first found
you just write: (with using System.Linq)

```
public void SelectRecepie(Recepie r)
{
    var result = recepies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.recepie.Equals(r)).isUnlocked;
    Debug.Log(result);
}
```

Comment: First throws an exception if the resultant enumeration is empty.  You could use "var result = recepies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.recepie.Equals(r))?.IsUnlocked ?? false;" to avoid that.

Comment: This will throw an exception when\if .Where() doesn't yield results.

Comment: Managed to get it to work with your solution, but i will go with the for loop the, thanks anyway for contribution!

Comment: @Gwr ,no problem!!

Answer (score 0):

When comparing [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) the comparison is determining if objects point to the same object (assuming class doesn't override `IEquatable`). What you are tying to find is an item with the same values.

The safest way to find an item within a collection is to use a unique identifier within the item combined with the [FirstOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1) method.

Given there is nothing that seems unique on `RecepieClass` the example below assumes there is an `Id` within `Recepie` referenced from `RecepieClass`.

```
var recipe = recepies.FirstOrDefault(r => r.recepie?.Id == 123456);
Debug.Log(recipe);
```

With the above example `recipe` will be `null` or the first `RecepieClass` with a `Recepie` matching the supplied id value (123456 in the example).